# Python ArgumentParser to Influxdb-Client

Tags: python, selenium, command-line-arguments, argparse, influxdb-python

I have a test script which sends test data to an Influxdb instance. To do so, I am utilizing InfluxDBClient to facilitate this. To make this script usable on my local machine as well as on my VM, I have setup Arguments.

The argument script looks like the below:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Setup for Automated Test')
parser.add_argument("--grafana_ip", dest="grafana_ip", action="store", default="localhost", help="The IP of the Grafana instance")
parser.add_argument("--grafana_port", dest="grafana_port", action="store", default="8086", help="The PORT of the Grafana instance")

args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

The test script is then setup as follows:

```py
from argument_onstream import args

client = InfluxDBClient(host=args.grafana_ip, port=args.grafana_port, database='TEST')

*do test*
```

The issue I am getting is that when I run the test script from the command line as follows:

```sh
python test.py --grafana_ip="10.10.10.10" --grafana_port="8086"
```

I get the following error:

```sh
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /write?db=TEST (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd2011b42b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

However, when I run a simple print within the test script I get the correct outputs:

```py
10.10.10.10 8086
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong?

Comment: Use `print(args)` to see what the parser has done.  If you like the values, then this isn't an `argparse` problem.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the input. I did state in the question that running a simple print returns the correct values. So, i would agree with you on it not being an argparse issue exactly. Still not sure where the breakdown is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I created a conftest.py file instead of using argparse.

The issue was that because I was running a startup script (main.py), which called test.py, and within test.py I had imported variables from main.py. The argparse variables being set in the CL, were being reverted back to default when the test.py imported the main.py.

Example below
argparse.py

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Setup for Automated Test')
parser.add_argument("--grafana_ip", dest="grafana_ip", action="store", default="localhost", help="The IP of the Grafana instance")
parser.add_argument("--grafana_port", dest="grafana_port", action="store", default="8086", help="The PORT of the Grafana instance")

args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

main.py

```py
from argparse import args

*setup for test*
```

test.py

```py
from main.py import stuff
from argparse import args

*do test*
```

I believe this is a circular import issue, along with poorly written code.

To correct the issue, I removed the main.py and argparse.py files. Added a conftest.py file, and allowed the conftest.py to pass variables to test.py.